# How to use this echo command with special character?

Tags: html, bash, shell

I want to use 2 or more quotes or special characters in this command and how do I do it?

```
echo "<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="link" rel="stylesheet">" >> file.html
```

file saved like this, i want it not to be like this and include quotation marks please help How do I add 2 or more quotation marks?

```
<meta charset=UTF-8> <link href=link rel=stylesheet>
```

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2140) and other common problems

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do. If you want to preserve the double quotes, you can use single quotes instead, like this:

```
echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="link" rel="stylesheet">'
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, I don't know what you want to do.
However, if you want to put a newline in an `echo`, use:

`echo -e '<meta charset=UTF-8>\n<link href=link rel=stylesheet>'`

or

`printf '%s\n%s' '<meta charset=UTF-8>' '<link href=link rel=stylesheet>'`.

EDIT:

Realized what you were trying to do. Use single quotes to preserve the double quotes, like so:

`echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<link href="link" rel="stylesheet">'`

or

`printf '%s\n%s' 'echo "<meta charset="UTF-8">' '<link href="link" rel="stylesheet">'`